# Weird Situation When Using "Clearable" on VSelect

Tags: vuetify.js, v-select

This is the intended usage of the clearable property on my  component:

1. On parent component:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col>
    <Selector :clearable="true"/>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

2. In the child component:

```
<v-select :clearable="clearable"/>

const props = defineProps({
  clearable: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});
```

Although I do see the clear icon on my component, the console keeps reporting:

**[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "clearable". Expected Boolean, got String with value "true".**

So, I experimented with directly assigning the values in the child component:

```
<v-select :clearable="true"/>
<v-select :clearable="false"/> <!-- Even with "false", the clear icon still appears -->
```

But encountered the same error messages. It appears we can only use this approach to avoid error messages:

```
<v-select clearable/>
```

However, how can I properly pass clearable as a prop from the parent component to the child component?

Comment: In general with Vue, adding prop name by itself to a component, in this case `clearable`, is really just [shorthand](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#boolean) for `:clearable="true"`.  There should be no functional difference.  There must be something else about your app causing issues, because the code provided so far does not generate any warnings or errors. Please provide minimal, runnable example using online sandbox, e.g. [Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I resolved the issue by making a simple adjustment to the parent component:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col>
    <Selector :clearable="clearable"/>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Where clearable is defined as:

```
const clearable = ref(true)
```